# iPhone TabBarController switching with selectedViewController doesn't show the view

Tags: iphone, tabbarcontroller

I'm getting crazy on this.

I've got a TabBarController with threw viewController and it's working ok in my app when I push the selection on the items.

When I try to call 
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]; 
(index 2 exists and the problem is with the index 1 too), I see the tabBarItem at position 2 selected (I mean the button) but the view will not appear (remaining at position 0 of the array item). I see that the viewController selected works in my debugger console but the view just doesn't appear.

Why it doesn't work? I've used it in previous apps and apparently there's nothing different.

Thanx for any suggestion you can provide.

Fabrizio

Comment: What happens if you try to change the selectedIndex directly?  eg. self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;.  Does the view show?

Comment: Yes it's the same. I've tried calling self.TabBarController.SelectedViewController on object 2 inside the AppDelegate and it works, but in my ViewController the View doesn't appear!

Comment: I've created a new project following the TabBarController template in XCode and putting self.TabBarController.SelectedViewController on object 1 (two ViewControllers in the TabBarController) inside viewDidLoad method of my first ViewController has no effect, so the same problem. I see the the TabBarItem on object 1 selected but no View appear. What it's so weird is that I got an old test with another TabBarController exactly to the new one and it works! I've created it before SDK4.

Comment: I found this: Where selectedIndex reflects the tab you wish to select (from left to right, starting at 0 for the first tab). The only thing to note, is that the UIViewController viewWillAppear method will not get called. So you may need to call this yourself, if you need to do something on the tab prior to it being displayed.

self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
[self.tabBarController.selectedViewController viewWillAppea:YES];

BUT THIS TOO...IT DOESN'T WORK. It must be something in my TabBarController but I don't see what :(((

Comment: I'm convinced that's something related to SDK4. Just try to build XCode template for the TabBarController, add self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; to the first ViewController and you will see that the TabBarItem will be selected but the View will not...

Answer (score 1):

It was a time problem, I was calling the setSelectedViewController too early and it couldn't switch.

Fixed using this:

[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

Fabrizio